# Multiple selection p:dataTable

Tags: primefaces

I want to select some rows from a data table and make some action on them. The rows from the table represent users of an application and the action is to disable them. When the method that disables the users is called the list of selected users is empty so no change is produced. I follow the primefaces showcase example. Can someon help to find the error?

***mypage.xhtml***

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    template="/templates/template-administrador.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="cuerpo">
            <p:dataTable id="tablaUsuarios" var="usuario"
                value="#{controller.users}" border="1" selectionMode="multiple"
                selection="#{controller.selectedUsers}" rowKey="#{usuario.id}">
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">ID</f:facet>#{usuario.id}</p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Email</f:facet>#{usuario.email}</p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">#{msgs.esAdministrador}</f:facet>#{usuario.isAdmin}</p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">#{msgs.usuarioTabla}</f:facet>#{usuario.login}</p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">#{msgs.estado}</f:facet>#{usuario.status}</p:column>

                <f:facet name="footer">
                    <p:commandButton process="tablaUsuarios"
                        value="Eliminar"
                        action="#{controller.eliminarUsuarios}"/>
                </f:facet>
            </p:dataTable>
    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

And the bean in charge of perform the action is this.

***ManagedBean.java***

```
    package uo.sdi.presentation;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

import uo.sdi.business.AdminService;
import uo.sdi.business.Services;
import uo.sdi.business.exception.BusinessException;
import uo.sdi.dto.User;

@ManagedBean(name = "controller")
@ViewScoped
public class ControllerBean implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 55555L;

    private String login, password;

    private User user;// Usuario que inicia la sesion en la aplicacion
    private List<User> users;// Lista de usuarios que tiene el administrador
    private List<User> selectedUsers;// Usuarios seleccionados de la lista
                                // anterior para ser eliminados

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    public List<User> getSelectedUsers() {
        return selectedUsers;
    }

    public void setSelectedUsers(List<User> selectedUsers) {
        this.selectedUsers = selectedUsers;
    }       

    public String validateUser() {

        String resultado;
        if (this.user != null)
            resultado = "error";
        else
            try {
                this.user = Services.getUserService().findLoggableUser(login,
                        password);
                if (this.user.getIsAdmin()) {
                    users = Services.getAdminService().findAllUsers();
                    resultado = "admin";
                } else
                    resultado = "usuario";

            } catch (BusinessException e) {
                // e.printStackTrace();
                resultado = "error";
            }    
        return resultado;
    }    

    public String eliminarUsuarios() {
        String resultado = "exito";
        AdminService service = Services.getAdminService();
        try {
            for(User user : selectedUsers)
                service.disableUser(user.getId());

            users = service.findAllUsers();

        } catch (BusinessException e) {
            resultado = "fracaso";
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return resultado;
    }

    public String listarUsuarios() {    
        String resultado = "exito";    
        try {
            users = Services.getAdminService().findAllUsers();
        } catch (BusinessException e) {
            resultado = "error";
            e.printStackTrace();
        }    
        return resultado;
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to initialisate your list in your getter like `selectedUsers= new ArrayList<User>()`

Comment: do not forget to make a condition like this `public List<User> getSelectedUsers() { if(selectedUsers == null){selectedUsers= new ArrayList<User>(); }
        return selectedUsers;
    }`

Comment: @YagamiLight this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: please add you error log i am sure it will help

Comment: @YagamiLight Well nothing is printed in the cosole. I debug the program and the problem is that when I select one row the content of that row is not added to the list of selectedUsers. But no error is shown.

Comment: add some some println for your selected list size to see if any thing wrong and if it is entering in the method delete

Comment: @YagamiLight It prints 0, and does not throw a nullpointer exception so the list is correctly initialized. Could it be related with the rowKey attribute of the dataTable?

Comment: add a form to your dataTable and instead `process = tablaUsuarios` make it `process = @form`

Comment: @YagamiLight thank you, it's working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve your problem just make your dataTable inside a form it will look like this :

```
<h:form >
 <p:dataTable id="tablaUsuarios" var="usuario" ...>

 ....
  <f:facet name="footer">
                <p:commandButton process="@form"
                    value="Eliminar"
                    action="#{controller.eliminarUsuarios}"/>
            </f:facet>
</h:form>
```

Comment: here you can find the answer please make it as an answer and why not upvoted it, also i will edit a little bit your question to make it feet as the SO recommande